# One child Component speak to another sibling in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a learning application following numerous online videos, and have come up with a small login screen. Huge progress for me.

(Code visible at https://github.com/CraigInBrisbane/ReactLearning)

My login component makes a WebAPI call to a service I have, that allows a user to login.

Site at http://cralis-001-site5.ftempurl.com/
(Click Login, u: craig@here.com, p: password)
It's a dummy learning site...

My code structure is like this:

[image]

What I am trying to do next is, on login success, do two things.

1. Goto /. i.e. Goto my home screen.
2. Update my NavBar, removing the Login button, and replacing it with a Logout button.

So I want to pass a prop to my Login component, which is a callback to a method `Somewhere`. That's the bit I don't know. Where is the root of my app? Where would I put the code that updates the Navbar? Somewhere I need a method, that can be called from my Login screen, that then updates my NavBar component.

I think my folder structure prevents me from doing this correctly.

And how would I redirect to the Home component on login success?

```
 handleSignin(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({canLogin: false});

        var request = {
            method: 'POST',
            URL: "http://cralis-001-site5.ftempurl.com/api/authenticate",
            data: this.state
        }

        fetchData(request).then(response=> {
            this.setState({ canLogin: this.validateForm() }); // Set the button if the state is valid.

            let divStyle = {
                padding: '8px 8px 8px 8px',
                color:  '#ffffff'
            }
            var type = response.success ? 'success' : 'error';
            var message = response.message;

            toast(<div style={divStyle}>{message}</div>,
            {        
              className: {
                background: type.toLowerCase() === 'success' ? '#316972' : '#fc751a'
              }
            });
        });

    }
```

All I'm doing is showing a Toast popup. How do I redirect to home?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to trigger a separate callback to change the NavBar, I would just use the current route to figure out whether to determine what to show in the NavBar. Since you are using react-router, each of your components passed into the Route components will be passed the [location](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) and [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) props. You can also use the [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) hoc to get access to those props as well if you don't want to pass the location and history props down from the top. Inside your NavBar component, you can do a check like `this.props.location.pathname === 'login'` to determine if you want to show logout or not.

To change the route, do `this.props.history.push('/')`

Comment: Adding that row after checking my response, results in "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: With regards "use the current route to figure out whether to determine what to show in the NavBar". What I need to do is check that the user has logged in, regardless of the path. So if I have a jwt in my "window.sessionStorage.accessToken". When I login, I populate that, and the 'Login' button should never appear again, but replaced with a 'Logout'.

Comment: The history prop is going to be passed to your SignIn component because that's the one that is passed into the Route (https://github.com/CraigInBrisbane/ReactLearning/blob/master/src/app.jsx#L20), so you should pass `<LoginBox history={this.props.history} />` or wrap LoginBox with withRouter if you don't want to have to pass the prop through: `export default withRouter(SingInBox)` in loginbox.jsx

Comment: With regards to the accessToken being present or not, I would pass a callback down from app.jsx that just does `this.setState({ accessToken })`. And then pass it down to your routes that need it.